# How to use ImageObserver in Graphics method drawImage()

Tags: java, image, applet, scale, draw

The method I am trying to use is the:
drawImage(image, int, int, int, int, ImageObserver) method
so that i can scale my image, on all the examples i've seen the ImageObserver should be this, but this doesn't seem to work(i.e. the only methods i have seen is: 
drawImage(image, int, int, ImageObserver), don't know if this makes a difference).

Here is my main class that is the applet:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends Applet implements Runnable{
    private Thread th;
    private Hitter hitter;

    //double buffering
    private Graphics dbg;
    private Image dbImage;

    public void init(){
        hitter = new Hitter(getImage(getCodeBase(), "Chitter.png"));
    }

    public void start(){
        th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
    }

    public void stop(){
        th.stop();
    }

    public void update(Graphics g){
        if(dbImage == null){
            dbImage = createImage(this.getSize().width, this.getSize().width);
            dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        }

        dbg.setColor(getBackground());
        dbg.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
        dbg.setColor(getForeground());
        paint(dbg);

        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        hitter.drawHitter(g);
    }

    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        while(true){
            repaint();

            try{
                Thread.sleep(15);
            }catch(InterruptedException ex){}

            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        }
    }

    public boolean mouseMove(Event e, int x, int y){
        hitter.move(x);

        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is the Hitter class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;

public class Hitter{
    private int x, y;
    private Image hitter;
    private int hitterWidth = 50, hitterHeight = 10;
    private int appletsizeX = 500, appletsizeY = 500;

    Hitter(Image i){
        hitter = i;
        start();
    }

    public void drawHitter(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(hitter, x, y, hitterWidth, hitterHeight, this);
    }

    public void move(int a){
        x = a;
    }

    public void start(){
        x = appletsizeX/2 - hitterWidth/2;
        y = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is too vague.  Please post code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 9):

Unless the class in which you are calling [`Graphics.drawImage(Image, int, int, int, int, ImageObserver)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) is an [`ImageObserver`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ImageObserver.html), using `this` as the argument for the `ImageObserver` will not work:

```
class MyClass {
  public void resizeImage() {
    Graphics g = getGraphicsObjectFromSomewhere();

    // The following line will not compile, as `MyClass` 
    // does not implement `ImageObserver`.
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 50, 50, this);
  }
}
```

If you're resizing an image which does not require an `ImageObserver` (such as a [`BufferedImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) that already contains the image you want to resize), then you can just hand over a `null`:

```
// The image we want to resize
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read("some-image.jpg");

// The Graphics object of the destination
// -- this will probably just be obtained from the destination image.
Graphics g = getGraphicsObjectFromSomewhere();

// Perform the resizing. Hand a `null` for the ImageObserver,
// as we don't need one.
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 50, 50, null);
```

That said, I'm going to throw in a little plug for my image resizing library [Thumbnailator](http://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/).

If all that is required is to resize an image, it can be accomplished as simple as the following code:

```
Thumbnails.of("path/to/image")
  .size(100, 100)
  .toFile("path/to/thumbnail");
```

Thumbnailator is flexible enough to accept `BufferedImage`s, `File`s, and `InputStream`s as input.

---

Seeing your edit, I would suggest to change the `Hitter` class, so that it will perform the resizing of the image in the constructor.

Since you are calling the `drawHitter` method on each call from the `Applet.drawImage`, the resize operation using `Graphics.drawImage` is being called many times, even when the `hitterWidth` and `hitterHeight` are, for all intents and purposes, constants.

Resizing the `Image` ahead of time, and drawing that pre-resized image in the `drawHitter` method will be more efficient.