# How can i add a "Player image" into Java?

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

Right, i am working on a new 2d/top down Java game. Recently, i have been teaching myself how to code in Java however i do have one problem... I have a box in my window which i am able to move around with the W,A,S AND D keys. All i want to know is how to replace that black box with an image(then later worry about animations). Here is my code (btw, this code is also the game engine).
Also here is the image that i am trying to add [Player image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUI8n.gif)

If anyone can help me it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

**Game.java**

```
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Game {

private final JFrame window = new JFrame();
private final ScreenFactory screenFactory;
private final GameThread gameThread;
private final KeyboardListener keyboardListener;
private final MousepadListener mousepadListener;

public Game(int windowX, int windowY, String title){
    window.setSize(windowX, windowY);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setFocusable(true);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setTitle("2D Game");
    window.setVisible(true);
    screenFactory = new ScreenFactory(this);
    gameThread = new GameThread(this);
    keyboardListener = new KeyboardListener();
    mousepadListener = new MousepadListener();


    window.add(gameThread);
    window.addKeyListener(keyboardListener);
    window.addMouseListener(mousepadListener);

    new Thread(gameThread).start();

}

public MousepadListener getMousepadListener(){
    return mousepadListener;
}

public KeyboardListener getKeyboardListener(){
    return keyboardListener;
}


public ScreenFactory getScreenFactory(){
    return screenFactory;
}


public JFrame getWindow(){
    return window;
}

}
```

**GameThread.java**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameThread extends JPanel implements Runnable{

private final Game game;

public GameThread(Game game){
    this.game = game;
    setFocusable(true);
}

public void run() {
    while (true){
        try {
            if(game.getScreenFactory().getCurrentScreen() !=null)
                game.getScreenFactory().getCurrentScreen().onUpdate();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void paint (Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    if(game.getScreenFactory().getCurrentScreen() !=null)
        game.getScreenFactory().getCurrentScreen() .onDraw(g2d);
    repaint();
}

}
```

**Screen.java**

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public abstract class Screen {

private final ScreenFactory screenFactory;

public Screen(ScreenFactory screenFactory ){
    this.screenFactory = screenFactory;
}

public abstract void onCreate();

public abstract void onUpdate();

public abstract void onDraw(Graphics2D g2d);

public ScreenFactory getScreenFactory(){
    return screenFactory;
}

}
```

**ScreenFactory.java**

```
public class ScreenFactory {

private final Game game;
private Screen screen;

public ScreenFactory(Game game){
    this.game = game;
}

public void showScreen(Screen screen){
    this.screen = screen;
    this.screen.onCreate(); 
}

public Screen getCurrentScreen(){
    return screen;
}

public Game getGame(){
    return game;
}

}
```

**KeyboardListener**

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyboardListener implements KeyListener {

private boolean[]keys = new boolean[256];

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    keys[event.getKeyCode()] = true;
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
    keys[event.getKeyCode()] = false;
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {

}

public boolean isKeyPressed(int key){
    return keys[key];
}

public boolean isKeyReleased(int key){
    return !keys[key];
}

}
```

**MousepadListener.java**

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class MousepadListener implements MouseListener{

private int mouseX, mouseY;
private boolean clicked;

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    mouseX = event.getX();
    mouseY = event.getY();
    clicked = true;
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
    mouseClicked(event);
    clicked = true;
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
    clicked = false;
}

public boolean isMousePressed(){
    return clicked;
}

public int getX(){
    return mouseX; 
}

public int getY(){
    return mouseY;
}

}
```

**TheGame**

```
public class TheGame {

private Game game;

public TheGame(){
    game = new Game(1280, 720, "2D Game");
          game.getScreenFactory()
.showScreenMy(newScreen(game.getScreenFactory()));
}

public static void main(String[] args){ 
    new TheGame();
}
}
```

**MyScreen**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class MyScreen extends Screen{

private int x = 0, y = 0;

public MyScreen(ScreenFactory screenFactory){
    super(screenFactory);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    System.out.println("Creating!...");
}

@Override
public void onUpdate() {
if (getScreenFactory()
.getGame().getKeyboardListener().isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_A))   
    x -= 2;

if (getScreenFactory()
.getGame().getKeyboardListener().isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_D))   
    x += 2;

if (getScreenFactory()
.getGame().getKeyboardListener().isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_W))   
    y -= 2;

if    (getScreenFactory()
.getGame().getKeyboardListener().isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_S))   
    y += 2;

if (y >= 720 - 72)
    y = 720 - 72;
if (y <= 0)
    y = 0;
if (x >= 1280 - 72)
    x = 1280 - 72;
if (x <= 0)
    x = 0;

}

@Override
public void onDraw(Graphics2D g2d) {
    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    g2d.fillRect(x, y, 72, 72);
}
}
```

Comment: In general, don't use swing to code games

Comment: this has been asked 1000 times im sure womeone will answer it why dont you continue to educate yourself by looking around for the answer??

Comment: how am i suppose to know if someone has asked this 1000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first read your image as a `BufferedImage`. And then draw it by `drawImage` method. Try this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class MyScreen extends Screen {

    private int x = 0, y = 0;

    private BufferedImage image;

    public MyScreen(ScreenFactory screenFactory) {
        super(screenFactory);

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("imagepath"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        System.out.println("Creating!...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate() {
        if (getScreenFactory().getGame().getKeyboardListener().isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_A))
            x -= 2;

        if (getScreenFactory().getGame().getKeyboardListener().isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_D))
            x += 2;

        if (getScreenFactory().getGame().getKeyboardListener().isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_W))
            y -= 2;

        if (getScreenFactory().getGame().getKeyboardListener().isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_S))
            y += 2;

        if (y >= 720 - 72)
            y = 720 - 72;
        if (y <= 0)
            y = 0;
        if (x >= 1280 - 72)
            x = 1280 - 72;
        if (x <= 0)
            x = 0;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.fillRect(x, y, 72, 72);
        g2d.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm... for some reason under ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("imagepath")); i get a red line saying Unhandled exception type IOException.

Comment: You can move the assigning part to the constructor and surround it with try catch block

Comment: It fixed the IOException however now i get new errors https://gyazo.com/e3a9fa84a97419c3bcf35abe28887390

Comment: Please try this for reading image: `image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("imagepath"));`

Comment: wow! Thank you soo much man. All i need to do is find out how to make it move with the KeyboardListener but i will try and find out my self without bothering you too much. Agian...Thank you.

Comment: fixed it! All i had to do is add x and y to the draw image like this g2d.drawImage(image,x, y, 72, 72, null);

Answer (score 0):

In your `MyScreen` class you have the following lines in your `onDraw` method:

```
g2d.setColor(Color.black);
g2d.fillRect(x, y, 72, 72);
```

`g2d` is a 2DGraphics object used to draw objects on the screen. In the line above, you're creating a black rectangle of equal side lengths (a square).

If you want to instead create an image, simply replace those two lines with the following:

```
g2d.drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, ImageObserver observer);
```

`Image img` is the Image object that you'd like to paint. The image itself must be 72 by 72 pixels to remain the same size as the original black square.

- To import the image you want, use `new ImageIcon("path/to/img.png").getImage()`

`int x` and `int y` are simply the coordinates of the destination.

`ImageObserver observer` is too in-depth for your purposes. You can set this to `null`. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638803/how-to-use-imageobserver-in-graphics-method-drawimage).

All of this information I got from [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html). Give their documentation a search next time before asking, you'll find that just about anything you're having trouble with is extensively covered! Also, this question has been asked numerous times, so googling `stackoverflow paint image java` should give you some quick answers.